# How can I create a function that creates any html element with any type of attributes?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I want to create a method that takes in an element type and any number of attribute types. For example,

```
createElement('div', {class: 'test-class', id: 'testId'})
```

or

```
createElement('input', {class: 'test-class', id: 'myInput', type: 'button', onclick: 'console.log('hello world')'})
```

This is what I have so far but I was just wondering if there's a better way to do it

```
function create(elementType, ...args) {
  const element = document.createElement(elementType);
  const [elementProps] = args;
  const {
    className,
    id,
    innerText,
    type,
    name,
    value,
    eventType,
    eventAction,
  } = elementProps[0];

  for (let prop in elementProps[0]) {
    if (typeof prop !== 'undefined') {
      element.className = className;
      element.id = id;
      element.innerText = innerText;
      element.type = type;
      element.name = name;
      element.value = value;
      element.addEventListener(eventType, eventAction, false);
    }
  }

  return element;
}
```

Comment: There is such a thing. It is called jQuery ;)

Comment: What if I don't want to use JQuery? Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: you can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute  to set attributes instead of assigning one by one

Comment: `function createElement(elementType, ...args) {
  const element = document.createElement(elementType);
  args.forEach(arg => {
    for (let prop in arg) {
      if (typeof prop !== 'undefined') {
        console.log(prop, arg[prop])
        element[prop] = arg[prop];
      }
    }
  })
  return element;
}` looks more like what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function cEl(elementType, ...args) {
  const element = document.createElement(elementType);
  const elementProps = args[0];
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(elementProps)) {
  if (typeof value != 'undefined') {
    if (key.indexOf('listener') == 0) { // Assume this is an event.
      element.addEventListener(key.substr(8), value, false);
    } else {
      element.setAttribute(key, value);
    }
  }
}
  return element;
}


var el = cEl('input', {
  class: 'test-class', 
  id: 'myInput', 
  type: 'button', 
  listenerclick: function(){console.log("hello world");} // Not a script but an actual function.
});
document.getElementById('d').append(el);
```

```html
<div id="d"></div>
```

By removing the attributes list the function now accepts any string as attribute.
since "on" might appear in other attributes, In this example I've changed it into a more unique identifier.

As for the function itself, it's up to you. You can define a full function or a function name. Just don't write it as text and try to convert it later to code. Try to avoid this if you can.